# How do search engines recognize search boxes on websites?

Tags: search, seo, bing

I've noticed that a lot of the time when i search something on Google, Google automatically uses the search function of relevant websites and return the result of the website search as if it was just another URL.

How do i let Google and other search engines know what is the search box on my own website and does Open Search has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you maybe mean the site search function via the google chrome omnibar?

to get there you just need to have a

- form with method type GET
- input type text element
- submit button
- on the root page of your domain

if users go directly to your root page and search something there, google learns of this form and adds it to the search engines accessible via the omnibar (the google chrome address bar).

did you mean this?

Comment: I didn't mean the omni-bar bar specifically, however it sounds by what you're describing that Google figures out for itself what's the search box of a website

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't use anyones search forms - it just finds a link to search results, you need to

1. Use GET for your search parameters to make this possible
2. Create links to common/useful search results pages
3. Make sure google finds those links

Google makes it look like just another URL because that is *exactly what it is*.

Most of the time though Google will do a better job than your search engine so actually doing this could lower the quality of results from your site...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does. It's impossible to spider sites in real time.

It's just a SEO technique some sites use to improve their ranking by spamming Google with fake results. They feed the Google bot with an endless stream of links to bogus pages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamdexing

Comment: I wouldn't call search results pages bogus - each of the tags pages on SO is a kind of search, i know i link people to search results, if i put that on a blog it would be indexable by google, and if google agrees with me that its good content then it may well get ranked reasonably highly...