# How Does Google Chrome know to use HNSearch to search Hacker News?

Tags: google-chrome, metadata

Hacker News' URL is news.ycombinator.com. When I input the full URL into Chrome, the right most part of the URL bar has the text "Press  to search HNSearch". HNSearch is a separate site which indexes and searches Hacker News. It is located at hnsearch.com. There is nothing in the metadata of Hacker News to indicate that HNSearch is the search engine of Hacker News.

So my question is, How does Google Chrome know to use HNSearch to search Hacker News?

Comment: Here you go: possible duplicate of [How do search engines recognize search boxes on websites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194101/how-do-search-engines-recognize-search-boxes-on-websites) — no metadata, Chrome just "guesses" when you use a form.

Answer (score 0):

Likely Chrome is asking Google for what search forms are available. The search form is using hnsearch.com.

Comment: How does Google know what search forms are available? Is there no metadata involved? How can it guess the search form for Hacker News but not for Stack Overflow?